# PHP Questions. Loops or If statement?

Tags: php, function, loops

I am trying to learn PHP while I write a basic application. I want a process whereby old words get put into an array `$oldWords = array();` so all `$words`, that have been used get inserted using `array_push(oldWords, $words)`.

Every time the code is executed, I want a process that finds a new word from `$wordList = array(...)`. However, I don't want to select any words that have already been used or are in `$oldWords`.

Right now I'm thinking about how I would go about this. I've been considering finding a new word via `$wordChooser = rand (1, $totalWords);` I've been thinking of using an `if/else` statement, but the problem is if `array_search($word, $doneWords)` finds a word, then I would need to renew the word and check it again.

This process seems extremely inefficient, and I'm considering a loop function but, which one, and what would be a good way to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Loop through array and use if statement if the researched word exist else create a new word.

Comment: Which look statement? Could you share a quick example?

Comment: oh so, while ($found == 0) if (word matches?) $found=1 else {reset word?}

Comment: Oh. I thought if the searched word exists you would want to show it if not push that inside an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused, PHP dies at the end of the execution of the script. However you are generating this array, could you also not at the same time generate what words haven't been used from word list? (The `array_diff` from all words to used words).

Or else, if there's another reason I'm missing, why can't you just use a loop and quickly find the first word in `$wordList` that's not in `$oldWord` in `O(n)`?

```
function generate_new_word() {
    foreach ($wordList as $word) {
        if (in_array($word, $oldWords)) {
            return $word; //Word hasn't been used
        }
    }
    return null; //All words have been used
}
```

Or, just do an array difference (less efficient though, since best case is it has to go through the entire array, while for the above it only has to go to the first word)

**EDIT: For random**

```
$newWordArray = array_diff($allWords, $oldWords); //List of all words in allWords that are not in oldWords
$randomNewWord = array_rand($newWordArray, 1);//Will get a new word, if there are any
```

Or unless you're interested in making your own datatype, the best case for this could possibly be in `O(log(n))`

Comment: I wish I would have clarrified, the word selection must remain random. All the words are in array $allWords = array(word1, word2...);

Comment: Yes, that's it! Now I suppose my concern would be, when there is no new words. What will that function output?

Comment: It will output a warning, but it will not fail the script. You can add a check (for example, and `if (count($newWordArray) >0)`) before doing it to avoid the warning.